# How to add photos to google doc from google sheet using apps script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-docs

I'm trying to add a list of images from my Google drive to a Google doc using Google apps script.
I made a list named **images_list** of links to the images that are in my Drive.
I've already added all the content I need to a template doc that I made using apps script and now I'm trying to add those images in the end of the doc.

I navigate in the doc using **bullet index** since my doc has a list of bullets in it.
I'm having some trouble to make the images appear after the last bullet even though I've referred to the last one, it's still adds them somewhere in the middle of the doc and I couldn't figure out why.

This is the code I'm using after I have the list with all the links:

```
  if(images_list[0]){
    for(var i=0; i<images_list.length; i++){
      try{
        var imageID = images_list[i].slice(32,65);
        var blob = DriveApp.getFileById(imageID).getBlob();
        var imgDoc = body.insertImage(bullet_index,blob);
        imgDoc.setWidth(400).setHeight(400)
        bullet_index = bullet_index+1
      }catch(e){}
    }
  }
```

How can I refer easily to the end of the doc?

Thanks!

Comment: I answered your first question, however according to the Stackoverflow guidelines, you should formulate one question per post - this helps to avoid confusion. So I recommend you to create a new post for your second question.

Comment: got it, good idea

Answer (score 0):

### Instead of [insertImage(childIndex, image)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/body#insertimagechildindex,-image)  use [appendImage(image)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/body#appendimageimage)

This will ensure that the image will be appended to a new paragraph.

Sample:

```js
  if(images_list[0]){
    for(var i=0; i<images_list.length; i++){
        var imageID = images_list[i].slice(32,65);
        var blob = DriveApp.getFileById(imageID).getBlob();
        var imgDoc = body.appendImage(blob);
        Utilities.sleep(500);
    }
  }
```

Note:

I added the [Utilities.sleep()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#sleepmilliseconds) at the end of the `for` loop. This forces the script to wait, to make sure that the images get inserted in the correct order.